# C++ Game AI only works in main

Tags: c++

I have a problem getting the AI to work if I do it in a subclass.

Here is my main loop in which I access the player and enemy classes for their move, logic, and show functions.

```
//Logic
        myPlayer.player_move();
        myEnemy.enemy_logic();
//Rendering
        myPlayer.player_show();
        myEnemy.enemy_show();
```

So I access the Player class's function that moves the player then I access the logic(AI) function of the Enemy Class.

```
void Enemy::enemy_move(){

eX -= 2;

}

void Enemy::enemy_logic(){
    Player myPlayer;
    if(myPlayer.x > SCREEN_WIDTH / 2){
        enemy_move();
    }
}
```

So if the Players x value is greater than half the screen, I want the enemy to start moving left

I can compile the program but when I move the player past the halfway point of the screen, the enemy does nothing. If I were to put this if statement in the main.cpp then it works fine. Any advice?

Comment: This isn't AI in any real sense, so I'm removing that tag.

Comment: @JohnDibling: A computer program making decisions (the decision to move the enemy) based on environmental conditions (the position of the player) is AI, even if it's not very sophisticated.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley:  By that definition you could say that all computer programs exhibit artificial intelligence.  I don't buy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're re-initializing your instance of the class `Player`. Instead, pass it as a parameter:

```
void Enemy::enemy_logic(Player myPlayer){
    if(myPlayer.x > SCREEN_WIDTH / 2){
        enemy_move();
    }
}
```

That way the function uses your instance, and not a new instance in a different scope.

Comment: Also, I've noticed you're using SDL. I recommend making a fast switch to SFML. http://www.sfml-dev.org/

Comment: I'm just beginning with game development and I thought SDL would be relatively easy. I'm going to eventually switch to something else.

Comment: That's why I started with SDL too, but I know both and I think SFML is much easier. More modern, more versatile, less C and more C++, and much better documentation. I know it'll be tough switching so soon if you're new to it, but just skim through a couple tutorials. I think you'll want to switch.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are initializing an instance of Player as myPlayer that is not connected to anything.

You should define a private variable for myPlayer inside your Enemy Class or pass a pointer to the Player class instance as an argument, in this way you will be able to maintain the state.

Comment: No, you'd better follow my second suggestion:         void Enemy::enemy_logic(Player* myPlayer) or pass by value void Enemy::enemy_logic(Player myPlayer)

Answer (score 1):

If your enemies depend on a single player you can "bind" each enmy to a player like this:

```
class Player
{
  Position m_x, m_y, m_z;
public:
  Position const & x (void) { return m_x; }
};

class Enemy
{
public:
  Enemy (Player &p) : m_player(p) { }
  Player & m_player;
  void logic (void)
  {
    if (m_player.x() > SCREEN_WIDTH/2)
    {
       move_x();
    }
  }
  void move_x (void) { /*...*/ }
};


int main (void)
{
    Player the_player;
    Enemy the_enemy(the_player);
    // move the player 
    the_enemy.logic(); // the_enemy knows the_player and acts accordingly
}
```